# Calculating determinant of a symmetric matrix where the $k$th row is given by $[a_{k-1},a_k,...,a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-(k-1)}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> For $j = 0,...,n$ set $a_{j} = a_{0} + jd$, where $a_{0}, d$ are fixed real numbers. Calculate the determinant of the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix
>   $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
>     a_{0}   & a_{1} & a_{2} &  \dots & a_{n}\\
>     a_{1} & a_{0}  & a_{1} & \dots & a_{n-1}\\
>     a_{2} & a_{1}  & a_{0} & \dots & a_{n-2}\\
>     \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
>     a_{n} & a_{n-1}  & a_{n-2} & \dots & a_{0} 
> \end{pmatrix}.$$

How to calculate that? I haven't found any property of determinant of symmetric matrix which could help.
I've tried to use Gaussian elimination (subtracting each row from the row above it), but it didn't work

Gaussian elimination(subtracting each row from the row above it)  brings to the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    -d   & d & d &  ... & d\\
    -d & -d  & d & ... & d\\
    -d & -d  & -d & .... & d\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    a_{n} & a_{n-1}  & a_{n-2} & ... & a_{0} 
\end{pmatrix} = d^{n-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    -1   & 1 & 1 &  ... & 1\\
    -1 & -1  & 1 & ... & 1\\
    -1 & -1  & -1 & .... & 1\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    a_{n} & a_{n-1}  & a_{n-2} & ... & a_{0} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is there a reason that you think there is a nice formula for this determinant?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah this is a problem from an old exam, so there must be a solution for sure

Comment: It would suffice to solve this problem for $a_0 = 0$ and $d = 1$, and this case can probably be solved if we use row-reduction to find a recurrence.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I added results of the calculations in the description

Comment: OP posted this, just after deleting a closed version where I suggested subtracting each row from the row above. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632464/calculate-a-determinant-of-symmetric-matrix-n1-times-n1 That's really an abuse of this website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah cause a question was closed and their message was "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one". I did what they recommended and posted a new one, lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtracting from each row the one above it, we shall obtain

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{0}   & a_{1} & a_{2} &  ... & a_{n}\\
    d & -d  & -d & ... & -d\\
    d & d  & -d & .... & -d\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    d & d  & d & ... & -d 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, subtracting from each column the one before it, we shall obtain

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{0}   & d & d &  ... & d\\
    d & -2d  & 0 & ... & 0\\
    d & 0  & -2d & .... & 0\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    d & 0  & 0 & ... & -2d 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Next, multiplying columns 2,3,$\ldots$,n+1 by $\frac{1}{2}$ and adding to the first we obtain:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{0}+\frac{nd}{2}   & d & d &  ... & d\\
    0 & -2d  & 0 & ... & 0\\
    0 & 0  & -2d & .... & 0\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    0 & 0  & 0 & ... & -2d 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, these row and column operations don't change the determinat of your matrix. Therefore $\det(A)=(a_o+\frac{nd}{2})(-2d)^n$.

Comment: thanks, and how did you came to subtracting from each column the one before it? Just Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Hi @manabou11 .  The idea is to create as many zeros as possible. It is usually simpler to calculate the determinant of a matrix with many zeros. Regards.

Comment: You could have gotten here long ago, manabou, if you had put any work into my suggestions at your previous go at this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632464/calculate-a-determinant-of-symmetric-matrix-n1-times-n1 which you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer:** If we use the matrix determinant lemma, then it suffices to consider the case of $a_0 = 0$ and $d = 1$.

With that said, let $A_n$ denote the matrix defined with your formula, with $a_0 = 0$ and $d = 1$.   Let $R$ denote an $n \times n$ identity matrix, where the first column has been replaced by $(1,0,\dots,0,n,1-n)$.  Note that 
$$
RA_nR^T = \pmatrix{-2n(n-1) & 0 & 2n\\
0 & A_{n-1} &-\\
2n & |}.
$$
Conclude that $\det(A_n) = -2n(n-1)\det(A_{n-1}) + 4n^2 \det(A_{n-2})$.